# Send post query and get json with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got the following code in jQuery:

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function(JSON) {
    alert(JSON);
});
```

This is post query, with JSON as the output.

How can I parse this JSON?

Comment: Your title needs to be changed.

Comment: jQuery should do it itself if the server passes correct content-type, else set dataType as json `$.post("test.php", {
    name: "John",
    time: "2pm"
}, 'json').done(function (JSON) {
    alert(JSON);
});`

Comment: Here's the api to parse json: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it:

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(data){
    // data will contain your object created from json
}, 'json');
```

If you specify `'json'` as last argument the json will automatically be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) method:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON);
var name = obj.name;
var time = obj.time;
```